# Terminal is referencing a device I've never heard of or seen

Tags: javascript, bash, unix, terminal

Does anyone know what this (HUAWEI_Mate_9_Pro-1e87b88) is referring to and why it says this? Currently, I'm working on a macbook air and using public WiFi (unsecured). This looks super fishy and shows up when I open my terminal.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkxiv.png]

Comment: Can you give a screenshot or a little more context or something. That's a model of phone, but it's hard to determine what/why you're seeing it. Probably you or someone has plugged in that phone at some point to charge.

Comment: Thanks, Sam. I thought I included a link. If you can't see it, maybe this link will work. https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkxiv.png

Comment: I'm just a bit blind apparently. =p I edited your post and put the image in there directly for you.

Comment: So I’ve never had anyone plug their phone into my laptop. What’s weird to me about this is that the device referenced is a phone. If this is of any value, I’m on public WiFi at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Seem like your internet ISP Router device

Comment: Thanks for the reply Wembo! That’s interesting. Given that the Huawei device is a smart phone, is that possible?

Comment: I guess yes, if is connected to your system

Comment: Thanks! You’re right. When I disconnect from WiFi, that device goes away. Super sketchy.

Comment: Will do. Because I'm new, my reputation is below 15 at the moment so my vote won't public display.

Answer (score 0):

This looks weird, but doesn't indicate an actual problem; just some confusion as various network elements try to be helpful, but actually just wind up propagating bad info. Here's a short summary of what most likely happened:

1. Some previous customer at [wherever this open WiFi is] connected their Mate 9 Pro to the WiFi. In its DHCP request to the router (to get an IP address for use on the WiFi network), the Mate 9 Pro identified itself as "HUAWEI_Mate_9_Pro-1e87b88".
2. The router allocated an IP address, sent it to the Mate 9 Pro, and also made a note in its internal table that that IP address belonged to "HUAWEI_Mate_9_Pro-1e87b88".
3. That customer left and their phone disconnected, but the router didn't remove the IP <-> name association.
4. You came in, joined the WiFi with your MacBook Air. The MBA's DHCP request *does not* contain identifying information (beyond the necessary MAC address).
5. The router allocated your MacBook the same IP address that the Mate 9 Pro had earlier, and since it doesn't have a replacement name to associate with it, it kept the old "HUAWEI_Mate_9_Pro-1e87b88".
6. To figure out its hostname, your MacBook sent off a DNS lookup to see what name is associated with this new IP address it's just acquired.
7. The router helpfully replied "your name is 'HUAWEI_Mate_9_Pro-1e87b88'".
8. Your MacBook believed it.

This is actually a fairly common "problem". I say "problem" because it doesn't really matter -- the hostname is used for display, and gets used in things like logfiles to keep track of which computer things happened on, but it isn't used for anything particularly important.

The main thing it causes is confusion (like yours).

Solution: ignore it, since it's not really significant.

Comment: Outside of the obvious security risks of me being connected to public WiFi, this answer made me feel way less concerned. Thanks for the reply, Gordon.